# How to convert list into dictionary in python?

Tags: python

I'm fetching value from database and I want to convert that value into dictionary.To fetch i have done in the following way

```
[dict((query.description[i][0], value) for i, value in enumerate(row)) for row in query.fetchall()]
```

I'm getting output as

```
[{'defrosting': 32.0, 'temperature': 42.0, 'timestamp': u'2017-04-25T11:30:15.207', 'hotwater': 3.0, 'humidity': 32.0, 'tds': 34.0, 'coldwater': 43.0}]
```

and i want to convert into this format

```
{'defrosting': 32.0, 'temperature': 42.0, 'timestamp': u'2017-04-25T11:30:15.207', 'hotwater': 3.0, 'humidity': 32.0, 'tds': 34.0, 'coldwater': 43.0}
```

Comment: you're making a list of dicts, what do you expect? note that there's only one result, which explains the list with one element. Just pick the first one...

Comment: @akashkarothiya not a dic comp, it's a set comp, and it won't work because dict is not hashable (your first comment was correct)

Comment: if I removed [ ] from ** [dict((query.description[i][0], value) for i, value in enumerate(row)) for row in query.fetchall()]**. It throws compile time error to **  query.description[i][0] **

Comment: Thanks @Jean-FrançoisFabre it worked by taking first element

Answer (score 2):

If you only need one result, any reason not to use `query.fetchone()`, it avoids getting all the results and discarding all but the first one:

```
{query.description[i][0]: value for i, value in enumerate(query.fetchone())}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating one dictionary per row of the results of your query. Does it always have exactly one result, or are you only ever interested in the first result? Then just pick the first element, as Jean-François Fabre said in the comments:

```
[dict((query.description[i][0], value) for i, value in enumerate(row))
    for row in query.fetchall()
][0]
```

Do the rows contain complimentary information (unlikely in this scenario)? Then make a single dictionary from it:

```
dict(
    (query.description[i][0], value)
    for row in query.fetchall()
    for i, value in enumerate(row)
    )
```

I personally find dictionary comprehensions more readable than the `dict` constructor:

```
{
 query.description[i][0]: value
 for row in query.fetchall()
 for i, value in enumerate(row)
}
```

Comment: while`pick the first element` if the list is empty then ? [0] will break

Comment: @Surajano I don't understand what you mean. If the list is empty, my first codeblock will throw an `IndexError` — rightly so. Or do you mean why construct a list at all?

Comment: @khelwood Whoops, fixed.